# R write to file / append at start of file

Tags: r, append, sparse-matrix

I am trying to write an input file that requires a single line in the first row telling if the file is sparse and if so how many variable levels there are.  I know how to append a single line to the end of a file, but can't find a way to append to the first line of a file.  Any suggestions?

```
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(Matrix)
library(SparseM)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$sepalOver5 <- ifelse(iris2$Sepal.Length >= 5, 1, -1) 
head(iris2)
summary(iris2)

trainRows <- sample(1:nrow(iris2), nrow(iris2) * .66, replace = F)
testRows <- which(!(1:nrow(iris2) %in% trainRows))
sum(testRows %in% trainRows)
sum(trainRows %in% testRows)

vtu1 <- c('Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width','Species')
dv1 <- dummyVars( ~., data = iris2[,vtu1], sparse = T)

train <- iris2[trainRows,]
test <- iris2[testRows,]

trainX <- as.matrix.csr(predict(dv1, train))
testX <- as.matrix.csr(predict(dv1, test))
trainY <- train[,'sepalOver5']
testY <- test[,'sepalOver5']

write.matrix.csr( as(trainX , "matrix.csr"), file= "amz.train" ,  fac = TRUE)
headString <- paste('sparse ',max(trainX@ja),sep = '')
```

I'd basically like to insert/append `headString` into `amz.train` in the first row.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not possible to prepend to the start of a file (and if there are ways, they would be really inefficient, since the information of the start of the file in memory is generally unknown. This holds for any programming language).

Three options come to mind:

- Read in the file, write the other information first, followed by the rest of the content of the file (might also be inefficient)
- Write the information you want to prepend first
- In the case you have a writer that cannot append (`write.matrix` for instance has no append option), you could try to merge this meta information with the data frame, and then writing it as a whole.

Since you are using a specialized format, I wouldn't recommend storing this meta-information this way.

Your file would look like:

```
sparse 6
1:3 2:5.2 3:2 6:1 
1:3.7 2:1.5 3:0.2 4:1 
1:3.2 2:6 3:1.8 6:1
```

And then there is option 4:

Rather, consider having a meta file which contains information such as file name, whether it is sparse or not and the number of levels. Here you could append, and if you would repeat this process it would be preferable. It will avoid problems of reading in weirdly formatted files.